# Is this new wheel out of true?

Tags: road-bike, wheels, wheel-truing

I just got a new road bike. Is this front wheel out of true? Or is it an acceptable amount of movement? I'm only using it to commute 10 miles a couple times a week.

Thanks.

https://streamable.com/m30il

Comment: It's worse than one would like to see on a new bike, but not bad enough to be a problem.  If this is a bike from a reputable shop you should take it back after maybe 200 miles break-in for (what should be) a free tuneup.

Answer (score 3):

The pads are positioned reasonably close to the rim so the brakes are probably be adjusted correctly. The does not appear to be rubbing on the pads. It will most likely not be a problem.

Whether this is acceptable on a new bike depends on the quality and cost of the bike. Most bicycle purchases come with a free tune-up after a short period of time, and a good bike store should deal with minor issues for no cost. Have the store take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The wheel itself looks reasonably true looking that the braking surface of the wheel versus the brake pad.  You should be fine riding with those wheels.  Only if you notice inconsistent braking over a long distance (e.g. coming to a traffic light on a downhill) where it feels like the brake pressure changes would you have any concern.

There does seem to be something a little funny with the tyre though.  Seems to have a bit of a bulge in it.  Might be worth taking the tyre off and checking the inner tube and putting it all back together to see if it was just mounted badly.